# GCC appears to be confusing C *.d dependency files with D language source code

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

When I compile my code, gcc appears to be confusing the .d files in my gcc options with D programming language source, and complains that it can't find the "cc1d" compiler. In summary, I get the following output when I run 'make':

```
gcc -c -I. -IUnity/src/ -Isrc/ -Ilib/ -DTEST test/Testworker.c -o build/objs/Testworker.o
gcc -c -I. -IUnity/src/ -Isrc/ -Ilib/ -DTEST src/worker.c -o build/objs/worker.o
gcc -o build/Testworker.out build/objs/Testworker.o build/objs/worker.o Unity/src/unity.o build/depends/Testworker.d
gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1d': execvp: No such file or directory
Makefile:56: recipe for target 'build/Testworker.out' failed
make: *** [build/Testworker.out] Error 1
```

How can I tell gcc that I really mean that my *.d files are dependencies, rather than more source files?

I tried renaming my intermediate *.d files to *.dep in my Makefile, but gcc doesn't recognize these, either...

My Makefile rule that is causing problems is this one:

```
$(PATHB)Test%.$(TARGET_EXTENSION): $(PATHO)Test%.o $(PATHO)%.o $(PATHU)unity.o $(PATHD)Test%.d
    $(LINK) -o $@ $^
```

The dependent Makefile rule to build the .d files is working fine:

```
    $(DEPEND) $@ $<
```

and I know that my .d files are being made. My one issue is when the

Comment: What are dependency files?

Comment: don't you mean to include the dependency files? please explain more what you mean with dependency file and/or post content of one dependency file as example.

Comment: Don't add the `.d` files to your link line.  They are for make, not for the linker.  You don't need this to be a prerequisite of your link line anyway: it tells how to rebuild _object_ files.

Comment: If you don't follow conventions, you will find yourself experiencing these issues. `.d` files aren't, by convention, C files. In C you get `.h` files (headers), and `.c` files (source files). Some people use `.inc` for files they include that include source / data later included in a `.c` file.